# Why cmp 2, 2 is't equal 0

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

```
extern putchar
extern exit
section .data

section .text
global main
main:

push 's'

mov eax, 2

cmp eax, 2

point:
call putchar
jz point

push 0
call exit
```

On the console I see only one 's' charcter.

**Compile and run:**

```
nasm -f elf ./prog.asm
gcc -m32 -o prog ./prog.o
./prog
```

Comment: You want `sub eax, 2` rather than `cmp eax, 2`

Comment: When dealing with assembly, you NEED to state the architecture.  Even if people can figure it out from linker arguments.

Comment: @BenVoigt: the tags do mention "linux".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cmp` *is* "equal to 0" (that is, it *does* set the ZF flag). However, the `call putchar` in the next line is trashing the flags set by `cmp`, so your `jz` does not work (more or less by accident). If you want to save the flags for later comparison, you could use `pushf` and `popf`, however this won't really work in your case since `putchar` will expect the character on the stack, not the flags.

Now, to answer the *actual* problem which you didn't state. I'll assume you want to print 's' two times. Here's how to do it properly:

```
  mov eax, 2 ; init counter

print_loop:
  push eax; save the counter since it will be trashed by putchar
  push 's'
  call putchar
  add esp, 4 ; restore the stack pointer since putchar is cdecl
  pop eax ; restore the saved counter
  dec eax ; decrement it
  jnz print_loop ; if it's not yet zero, do another loop
```

`add esp, 4` can be replaced by another `pop eax` for slightly shorter code.

Answer (score 2):

The result of doing a `cmp` is that flags get set, `zf` for zero, and so on. You can then either branch on whether or not the flag was set or use one of the `set?` instructions to have a value, e.g. the `al` register, set based on whether or not the flag was set.